# Shopware 4 Rest API Article link with Images(Media)

Tags: api, rest, import, shopware

I want to Link Articles with Medias by using the Rest API.

I had the Article ID and the ID from the Images (Media) an now want to send an Article Update to the API to update the images.

Is this possible?

Like this?

```
$article[]=array(
    'id'=>'13,
    'images'=>array('media_id' => 4)    
);

$return = $client->put('articles',array($article);
```

Answer (score 2):

it needs to be called "mediaId", so

```
$article[] = array(
    'id' => '13',
    'images' => array(
        array('mediaId' => 1),
        array('mediaId' => 2),
    )
);
```

this should work to assign media items by ID.